# R position the header

Tags: r

I have a table in R code and this is how the table looks below.

```
Age Sex
10   20
```

I want to position the header in the column side

```
Age    10
Sex    20
```

Any idea on how to position the header in the left side.

Comment: You can simply transpose the table (or dataframe) using the [built-in function `t()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/t.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just transform it. `t()`

```
df <- as.data.frame(t(starting_df))
```